# Open popup in a new window by clicking a button in Javascript Alert

Tags: javascript, html, window, hosting, alert

I'm using this code:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
window.alert("Click Ok If Over 18");
window.open(
  '.html', 
  '_blank' // <- This is what makes it open in a new window.
);
</script>
```

I need to add this code for open a popup in new window:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='address popup'></script>
```

If I add it in this way:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.alert("Click Ok If Over 18");
window.open(
  'address popup', 
  '_blank' // <- This is what makes it open in a new window.
);
</script>
```

It doesn't open as expected. I see only text.
Maybe it's because I did not use `src:`.
What I can do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first parameter of `window.open()` needs to be the URL of the page you want to open in the popup.

Rather than using an alert, sounds like you should use a [confirm](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_confirm.asp). Alert doesn't actually allow the user to say they aren't 18; even if they close the alert instead of hitting "ok", it'll still continue to open your pop-up. But confirm() gives them an "ok" button and a "cancel" button, so they can choose.

So altogether, here's what your code might look like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var isEighteen = window.confirm("Click Ok If Over 18");
if (isEighteen) { // if they clicked "ok"
    window.open(
      'http://example.com/popup-is18.html', 
      '_blank'
    );
} else { // if they clicked "cancel"
    window.open(
      'http://example.com/popup-not18.html', 
      '_blank'
    );
}
</script>
```

It looks like you were trying to include the JavaScript from another file. If you did that, you'd want to put everything inside of the script tag above into a file, `some_name_you_can_make_up.js`, and then do this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://example.com/some_name_you_can_make_up.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply: But I that way I can add window.open in CANC button? Window.open open well all links but not my popup code within src, why?

Comment: (i'm assuming "CANC" means "cancel") Sure, just add an else condition to the if statement I wrote; I'll edit my post to demonstrate.